# What should I monitor on the SQL Server machine?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, alerts

I need to create some alerts, logging jobs and monitors on a machine that is going to run SQL Server 2012 Standard for an ERP system.

The OS will be Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard/Datacenter (if it matters).

I am planning to implement: server performance monitors (processor time, load, memory used, reads/writes to disk, disk space).

I don't know what should I be logging in terms of the database/SQL Server instance. I thought about autogrowth operations on the database and transaction log files. 
I guess I should be monitoring locks, transactions, connections and a few more things. But what exactly? Which activities should be logged only and which should be emailed to me ASAP?

I will greatly appreciate your advice as I'm a beginner in database administration.

Comment: Understand possible restrictions but one bit of advise: Don't put a version of SQL Server on a OS version that will be out of support before SQL Server will be.

Comment: The company decided to use Windows 2008 R2 because all the servers run on this version and using Win 2012 would be a problem in terms of licensing for remote desktop connections. Can you provide me with a few strong arguments why we should use Windows 2012 (and SQL Server 2014 - that case is still open)?

Comment: Mainstream support for Window Server 2008 R2 ends January 13, 2015. The last service pack released for Window Server 2008 R2 was in what 2010 I think. They are not going to release another one now that Window Server 2012 R2 is in full swing.

Comment: With regards to licensing for Remote Desktop, why are they allowing remote desktop connections? I would block this ability if I was allowed to because there is no reason to do that anymore unless I am patching or have a VERY specific reason and those would not require any more licenses that are available out of the box.

Comment: The remote connections are used by administrators only from the local network or VPN. How else would you access a Windows Server machine? Or do you suggest to run a core installation?

Comment: Its little difficult to tell what you should exactly monitor perhaps every thing should be monitored but priority should be given to Blocking, CPU, Disk Space and errorlog. Its difficult to point you to script upfront I would like you to filter your question and make it little precise. Otherwise best solution would be buy a monitoring tool IF you can

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get server cpu, memory, network usage from SQL Server](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69229/how-to-get-server-cpu-memory-network-usage-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options you mention (file auto grow for example) are already logged in the SQL Server default trace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx

Other options for your own monitoring can be done via windows perfmon to monitor all kind of windows or SQL Server variables. You could also save output from any of the SQL Server DMV to store various options over time (query plan statistics, wait types, memory, locks etc).

You could investigate using the new Management Data Warehouse feature to collate lots of information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677306.aspx.

Having said all of that, that is going to be a steep learning curve and it is difficult to give a definitive answer. As a beginner is buying a third party tool that will do all this monitoring for you an option? Some packages are: -

- http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/performance-advisor/sql-server-performance
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/

Comment: Also System Center Operations Manager with the SQL Server management packs (with the appropriate cost and learning curve that comes with operations management software).